# How can I bind a hidden attribute to a computed function (Polymer 1.0)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to bind a 'hidden' attribute to the outcome of two separate Boolean property values. For example, I want to hide the element when !boolA || boolB.

The template contains:

```
<img src='...' hidden={{!src || isLoaded}}>
```

And then I define the properties:

```
Polymer({

  is: 'thingy-thing',

  properties: {
    src: {
      type: String
    },
    isLoaded: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false
    }
  }
});
```

I know that I cannot combine these both into the same expression, so I tried to use a computed property, but I am not having any success. It seems that I also need to use "reflectToAttribute", however I am not understanding how that works. I have tried multiple combinations of properties, but I could use someone pointing me in the right direction.

My most recent combo was a property of:

```
hideSpinner: {
    type: Boolean,
    computed: 'computeHideSpinner(src,loaded)',
    reflectToAttribute: true
  }
```

and I exposed a function of 'computeHideSpinner', however this function is never executed (the debugger line is never hit).

```
computeHideSpinner: function(src, loaded) {
  debugger;
  return (!src || loaded);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I thought it would throw it out here incase this might help anyone else.

My function was never running, as one of my values had an undefined value.  From the docs:

"The computing function is not called until all dependent properties are defined (!=undefined). So each dependent properties should have a default value defined in properties (or otherwise be initialized to a non-undefined value) to ensure the function value is computed."

My solution was to default src to an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

To bind to an attribute use a dollar sign ($).
And to make sure the binding is refreshed whenever a variable changes, include the observed variables as arguments to the function call.

Also note, when one-way binding **use brackets instead of braces** to increase performance.

For example:

html:

```
<img src="source.jpg" hidden$="[[hideSpinner(src,loaded)]]">
```

Polymer script:

```
hideSpinner: function(src,loaded) {
  return (!src || loaded);
}
```

**Here's [a working example on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/pefeyi/edit?html,output)**

Comment: Thanks, I also realized that I had confused one-way binding with one-time binding. I am coming from an Angular background, so I keep getting caught on old habits.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for attribute bindings contains a $ character ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)).

```
<img src='...' hidden$={{hideSpinner}}>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw this, and tried it. It also doesn't work. 'computeHideSpinner' is still never triggered.

I am not clear what the difference between reflectToAttribute and binding to the attribute with "$=" would be, however neither of them are doing anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I thought it would throw it out here incase this might help anyone else. My function was never running, as one of my values had an undefined value. From the docs: "The computing function is not called until all dependent properties are defined (!=undefined). So each dependent properties should have a default value defined in properties (or otherwise be initialized to a non-undefined value) to ensure the function value is computed." My solution was to default src to an empty string.

On top of that, I had a few other issues that Kevin and Maria were able to help with.